# How to fix URLEncoder related issues?

Tags: java, angular, development-environment, urlencode, production-environment

I am having issues with my URL encoder, it is working locally and on stage, but not working on live.

I am using filters to get brand names, but some of those brand names have spaces. When I send a request on live, it returns a 500 error.

> java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 236:
> http://gateway-service/deal-solution-service/api/deals?categories=false&phonesAndSim=false&lteAndSim=false&tabletsAndLaptops=false&connectivity=false&priceMin=0&priceMax=50000&duration36=false&duration24=false&brand=Huawei
> Spa

It was supposed to take care of this "Huawei Spa"

my serviceImpl:

```java
@Override
public Collection<String> getDistinctBrands(Filter1 productFilter) {
    List<String> distinctBrands = new ArrayList<>();

    if (productFilter != null && productFilter.getBrand() != null && !productFilter.getBrand().isEmpty()) {
        String encodedBrand = URLEncoder.encode(productFilter.getBrand(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        distinctBrands.addAll(Arrays.asList(encodedBrand.split("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\-_']+")));
    } else {
        distinctBrands = dealRepository.findDistinctBrands();
    }
    return distinctBrands;
}
```

my controller:

```java
@Override
public ResponseEntity<List<String>> getDistinctBrands(Filter1 filter) {
    Collection<String> distinctBrands = dealService.getDistinctBrands(filter);
    if (!distinctBrands.isEmpty()) {
        List<String> decodedBrands = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String brand : distinctBrands) {
            decodedBrands.add(URLDecoder.decode(brand, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(decodedBrands);
    } else {
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }
}
```

I was having issues when using filters (filtering by brand name with spaces), I then added a URL encoder, and it started working locally and on the staging environment, but it still didn't work on live.

If my brand name contains spaces, I want to encode my URL to fill in the spaces.

Comment: You should encode the collection, not just the individual brands. IOW you should encode the entire 'value' part of the argument, and indeed the 'key' part as well, and for all arguments, not just this one.

Comment: You say that you get a java.net.URISyntaxException. But in your code does not show any code which will fire this exception. So this specefic error comes from else where. Did you check the stack trace

Answer (score -1, accepted):

based on the description and snippets, your approach to url encoding seems to be more or less correct. The error you are seeing indicates that there is an issue with white space encoding.

When you encode a string like "Huawei Spa" spaces should be replaced with '+' or '%20'.
You can encode it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP) and test on your environment.

The fact that it works locally and not on production may indicate discrepancy in how URLs are interpreted across those environments. Everything between client and the app, including server, reverse proxies and other configurations can cause such behavior.

For URLEncoder reference please check official [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html)

Comment: It’s not correct. He is encoding one element and then forming a collection, instead of forming a collection and then encoding that.

Comment: Thanks, the issue was with the URIComponentBuilder                                              private String buildUri(final ProxyExchange<?> proxy, final MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams) {
    return UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(rewritePath(proxy))
                                .queryParams(queryParams)
                                .build()
                                .toUriString();
}